# ¿Cómo hacer una condición en el controlador con laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

Tengo una funcion en mi controlador que se encarga de confirmar si el usuario cumple los requisito(puntos) para reclamar premios...mi problema es que si el usuario tiene 100 puntos y el premio cuesta 500 en teoria no deberia de poder reclamar ese premio, pero con el codigo que he hecho no me funciona y el usuario si pasa esa condicion

este es mi codigo en el controlador

```
public function reclamarpremios(Request $request)
{
    $vago_puntos = request('vago_puntos');
    $premioID = request('id');
    $puntaje = request('puntaje');
    $perfil_users_app_id = request('perfil_users_app_id');
    $us = UserAppPerfil::where('id',$perfil_users_app_id);
    $reclamo = Premios::where('id',$premioID)->where('puntos','>=',$vago_puntos);
    if($reclamo->count()>0) 
    {
        $us->decrement('vago_puntos',$puntaje);
        $reclamo->increment('veces_reclamado');
        return response()->json([$us,$reclamo,'message' => 'Felicidades has reclamado esta promocion, el equipo de vagos estara en contacto con tigo para obtorgarte tu premio'],200);

    }else{
        return response()->json(['message'=>'No tienes los suficientes vagos puntos'],422);  
    }

}
```

mi tabla premios [image: tabla]

Comment: Si se supone que el premio solo se puede reclamar cuando tienes 100 puntos, entonces ¿por qué haces un `count()`, no deberías hacer una suma de los valores de esa columna?

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos lo que está almacenado en `$reclamo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

despues de estar mucho a prueba y error asi lo resolvi amigos

```
public function reclamarpremios(Request $request)
{
    $premioID = request('id');
    $puntaje = request('puntaje');
    $perfil_users_app_id = request('perfil_users_app_id');
    $us = UserAppPerfil::where('id',$perfil_users_app_id)->first();
    if($reclamo = Premios::where('id',$premioID)->where('puntos','<=',$us->vago_puntos)->first())
    {
        $us->decrement('vago_puntos',$puntaje);
        $us->increment('premios_ganados');
        $reclamo->increment('veces_reclamado');
        return response()->json([$reclamo,$us,'message'=>'Felicidades has reclamado esta promocion, el equipo de vagos estara en contacto con tigo para obtorgarte tu premio'],200);
    }else{
        return response()->json(['message'=>'No tienes los suficientes vagos puntos'],422);
    }

}
```

me hacia falta realizar la busqueda del where con un firsts para ser para especificos en la busqueda... y otra cosa que me confundio es que pense que esta forma de los operadores significaba mayor e igual que(>=)pero en realidad tenia que usar <=

Comment: `>=` es mayor igual y `<=` es menor o igual

Comment: justamente eso se yo...pero de esta forma no es valido...te pongo por ejemplo yo tengo 1000 puntos y un premio vale 500 ...de esta forma >= me deberia de pasar..pero me dice que tengo los puntos insuficientes...y de esa misma forma >= si tengo 200 puntos y el premio vale 500 entonces puedo reclamarlo(cosa que no deberia ser cierto)...pero si lo pongo de esta forma <= entonces si puedo reclamar el premio con la logica que es...todas esas pruebas las hice con el postman...y funciono ...esta raro eso...lo unico que se me ocurre son las tablas de verdad y los diagramas de venn

Comment: Independientemente de que te funcione o no, no entiendo por que pasas en el Request  el `puntuaje` y `perfil_users_app_id`, viendo la logica esto podria dar lugar a que un usuario mas listo de la cuenta reclame los premios sin afectar su puntuaje o que un usuario reclamen premios para otro usuario.

Comment: tienes razon ..le pasaba el puntaje para luego restarle eso a los puntos del usuario...pero como ya estoy haciendo la consulta mejor lo paso desde el dato de la base ya con eso esto-> `$reclamo->puntos` lo solucion...en si toda esa funcion es parte de un controlador que utilizo como api...lo consumo desde una app de ionic...muchas gracias por la recomendacion

Answer (score 1):

es posible que en ésta linea:

```
$reclamo = Premios::where('id',$premioID)->where('puntos','>=',$vago_puntos);
```

te haga falta un `->get()`

quedando asi:

```
$reclamo = Premios::where('id',$premioID)->where('puntos','>=',$vago_puntos)->get();
```

Comment: ya he  probado poniendole un get...pero sigui igual :(

Comment: Según la documentación de laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests para acceder a los valores de la petición deberias hacer `$request->nombre_campo` no `request('nombre_campo')`

Comment: @Arnuelgm Según la documentación, usar el helper `request()` también es válido: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-request